# Why do continuations not have useful arity?

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations

Consider the following code:

```
(call-with-values
    (lambda ()
      (call/cc (lambda (k)
         (k k k))))
  (lambda (x y)
    (procedure-arity y)))
```

It's pretty obvious here that the continuation at the point of the `call/cc` call is the lambda on the right-hand side, so its arity should be 2. However, the return value of the above (in Racket) is `(arity-at-least 0)` instead.

Indeed, running similar code in Guile (substituting `procedure-minimum-arity` for `procedure-arity`) shows that the continuation also supposedly allows any number of arguments, even though it's pretty clearly not the case.

So, why is that? As far as I understand (correct me if my understanding is wrong), the arity of a continuation is pretty straightforward: it's 1 except in the context of `call-with-values`, in which case it's whatever the arity of the right-hand-side lambda is. (Which, granted, can be complicated if it's a `case-lambda` or the like, but no more complicated than if you were calling `(procedure-arity (case-lambda ...))` directly.)

Comment: IMO, it should be any number of arguments, as when the explicit continuation is created with call/cc, the context is unknown until the continuation is actually called. I think the definition of `values` in the spec (R5/6) sums this up nicely.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how `values` implies that the continuation has arbitrary arity. You're not allowed to return a different number of values from what the continuation supports. :-) Thus, `(+ (values 1 2 3) 42)` is not valid: in this context (assuming `values` as defined in R5RS), the continuation so created has arity 1, nothing else.

Comment: Also with `call-with-values`, the *consumer* determines the arity, not the *producer*.

Comment: Of course. So my question is, why doesn't the continuation have the arity of the consumer? :-)

Comment: How would it work if you have: `(call-with-values some-proc list)`? There is no way `some-proc` can determine the expected number of values at the time of its definition. Does that make sense? The compiler however is free to optimize the code as in your post to something more specific (as it can be determined). It is not required to share this info however ;p

Comment: `(procedure-arity list)` is `(arity-at-least 0)`. So in this case, it's entirely appropriate for `(call-with-values (lambda () (call/cc values)) list)` to have arity `(arity-at-least 0)` too. So, that's a straw man argument. :-)

Comment: Perhaps I explained wrong :) Take for example: `(define (foo) (values 1 2 3)) (call-with-values foo list)` Given the definition of `values`, `foo` has no idea what the actual arity of the implied continuation is. It only expects the continuation to accept 3 values. This is only verified when the continuation is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way to see the same is:

```
(call-with-values
  (lambda () (error 'arity "~v" (procedure-arity (call/cc (λ (k) k)))))
  (lambda (x y) (procedure-arity y)))
```

and even simpler:

```
(procedure-arity (call/cc (λ (x) x)))
```

And for your question -- it's clear in the first case that the continuation expects two inputs, but cases like that are not too common.  Eg, they're usually such examples, whereas "real code" would use `define-values` or have some unknown continuation, where the continuations that `call/cc` creates can have different arities depending on the context that they were created at.  This means that there's not much point in trying to figure out these rare cases where the continuation's arity is known.

Footnote:

```
;; nonsensical, but shows the point
(define (foo) (call/cc (λ (x) x)))
(define x (foo))
(define-values [y z] (foo))
```

Comment: Wait, are you saying that there are times where the continuation's arity is _unknown_ at the point of its capture? Maybe I'm not thinking hard enough about this.

Comment: Yeah, see footnote.  Unless you want each of these continuations to dynamically get different arities...  (But I have to run, so can't spend more time on this now.)

Comment: The dynamic approach was indeed what I had in mind when I asked the question, but perhaps it's not viable. I should try creating a proof-of-concept to see if this would even work. Meanwhile, have a big green tick. I mean, you've waited 2 months for it. :-)